# Verbs within a prepostional phrase

Tags: verbs, prepositions

In the following two sentences I see verbs being used within prepositional phrases. Is this acceptable in casual conversation? The meanings in both cases are clear.

> It depends on what the meaning of "is" is.
>
> I washed the dog with that soap you got.

Also, in the first example, "is" is being used as an object noun, followed by a verb.

Answer (score 1):

You already know the answer to the first sentence.....use double quotes:

*It depends on what the meaning of "is" is.*

In the second sentence, restructured:

*I washed the dog with the soap that you got.*

the phrase starting with **with** modifies the predicate and the phrase starting with **that** modifies soap.

There is nothing wrong with using these phrases in this way.

Comment: The _with_ phrase does **not** modify _dog_, it modifies the predicate _washed the dog_.

Comment: @ColinFine  you are correct

Comment: But only the semantics can tell you that: structurally, it could equally well modify _dog_, and people get hours of fun from wilfully misinterpreting such sentences

Comment: That's the basis of the classic Groucho Marx joke _One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got in my pajamas, I don't know._

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are quite normal.

In the first case, the object of the preposition *with* is the embedded clause *what the meaning of "is" is*.

In the second case, the noun phrase *the soap that you got*  contains the embedded relative clause *that you got*.